# Error: The buffer manager cannot extend the file "C:\Users\user_name\... .tmp" to length 99996168 bytes. There was insufficient disk space

Tags: sql-server, ssis, buffer, ssis-2012

We are running a package which is run on around 1 million of records and the package uses multiple sorts and joins. The package is getting aborted with the below error-

Error: The buffer manager cannot extend the file "C:\Users\ *user_name* \AppData\Local\Temp\2\DTS{DCC58934-0E3F-4E9D-9858-E2E0A39002A2}.tmp" to length 99996168 bytes. 
There was insufficient disk space.

We have tried increasing the DefaultBufferSize to 100 MB and the C:\ drive also has free space of around 10 GB. We have also tried including a batch process which would clear the \tmp  directory before the package starts. But the issue persists.

The user who is running the package has admin rights on the system. We haven't yet tried setting the BufferTempStoragePath. Please suggest with other workarounds.

Thanks!

Comment: Have your DBA monitor the disk space during the package execution.

Comment: Does your flow use the sort component? If so, change the BufferTempStoragePath to different location. This location would need the appropriate permissions on the account running the package to extend the file.

Comment: The execution was done on the client server through WebEx and we couldn't get their DBA to check the disk space

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error. In my case the reference dataset have 4+ million data and then comparing with source data. I am using lookup transformation control with full cache. When package executes memory gets full and error appears. What I understood with this behavior is that when memory gets full, virtual memory assist and provide some more space to load buffer but unfortunately virtual memory also fail to help more; SSIS package gets crash and error appears as mentioned in tile.

Initial query used in Lookup transformation control: Select customerid, customercode from customerBase(nolock) /*when crm get loaded everytime record size increases using same package*/

I then try to minimize to load of reference dataset in a lookup transformation so that among 4+ million, only pull limited recordset and load it into memory easily.

Modify the query :Select customerid, customercode from customerBase(nolock) cst inner join cityBase(nolock) cty on cst.cityid=cty.cityid where cityname='Karachi'

Note: It may vary in your scenario how to load minimum reference dataset in memory using lookup transformation control of SSIS. Using such queries with full cache then ssis match source data with reference dataset.

Hope this approach may help to someone.

Thanks